# How to measure the total current driven in a building by observing the electricity meter?

Tags: mains

Electricity meters show power. How can I measure roughly how many total current in amperes is driven at an instant in a building including a 3 phase AC motor?

Comment: `P = U*I`, Watts = Volts * Ampères -> `I=P/U`, A = W/V, where `U` = your main's nominal line voltage.

Comment: I read around 95000kWh. Possible to estimate the current drawn?

Comment: @user16307 Divide it by the used voltage times three. If your phases are not used symmetrically you have no means to calculate the individual load from this one figure.

Comment: U mean 95000/(230x3) ???

Comment: @user16307 that's what I meant.

Comment: It is 130A it cant be that high

Comment: Im asking rms current

Comment: I'd just like to join in here to say that whether humor is involved or not in saying that 'instant current' is zero it doesn't change the fact that the statement is just plain wrong. And OP, if you really are using 95MW the current figure is right.

Comment: "Electricity meters show power.' No, they show **energy used** (power x time) so just dividing by a voltage doesn't work, that will produce an amp-hr value.

Comment: Sorry my comment was moronic. You have to divide the term by the time the measurment has run, too. Thanks @JimDearden

Comment: How can I convert amp-he to ampere?

Comment: @user16307: only if you know, for how long the measurement has run.

Comment: \$Power=\frac{Energy}{Time}\$

Comment: @user16307: Just wondering: why do you care about the current? You pay for the kWh and, possibly, a penalty if your kVArh goes too high. Are you worried about fusing, cable size or what?

Comment: @Transistor there is a limitation of max. current draw from the electricity network(according to some law which i dont know). i had to find out whether the facility altogether at its maximum drawing more than that amount.

Comment: @user16307: Thanks. I know you've accepted Andy's answer but depending on the type of meter you might be able to work out the power factor. Can you add meter details and / or a photo and we'll see if there is kVArh (reactive power) measurement on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Electricity meters show power

No, they show power integrated over a time period (energy) i.e. kWhours and not kW actually being consumed in a particular moment. On this basis, you cannot know what the load current is in a particular "instant".

You could set a stop watch and record the change in kWhours. Then convert this back to kW (knowing the time period elapsed on the stop watch). Then estimate average RMS current over that time period but you'll have to take a stab at power factor which by no means will be either unity or constant over various load conditions that the 3ph motor might encounter over that time period.

Comment: So relating to OP's comment he probably saw an energy meter not a power meter.

Comment: Well some of them show power. We have some fancy modern thingies in Italy, they can trip the main switch if you go over max power of some x% for more than some t time. And they show you the power ofc. I am with you anyway, I highly doubt OP has a way to access a power meter that shows 95MW (figure given in comments). That's probably MWh.

Comment: Yes but if I wait 5 hours and take two kWhr readings  and the diffetence in kWhr and 5 hr time; can I estimate the current driven?

Comment: However an average current can be calculated by noting two readings after a short interval(maybe 1hour for example) and dividing the difference of those two readings by that interval and dividing again by voltage. Reading difference = energy consumed. Energy / time = Power. Power/rms voltage = rms Current.

Comment: assıming load is constant

Comment: Power/rms voltage or power/ (3 x rmsVoltage)

Comment: @user16307 if you wait 1 hour, the difference in kWh readings is average kW consumed in that hour. If you wait 5 hours then divide the difference by 5 to get average kW consumed in those 5 hours. Divide by 3 to get phase power then divide by 230V (or whatever your phase voltage is) to get average RMS current per phase but this then needs to be divided by the average power factor of the motor and this might be 0.5 or even lower under some loads. It might even be close to unity if PF correction is used.

Comment: i think motor has seperate reading. if no motor no neef power factor right?

Comment: @user16307 Not only motors have powerfactors different than 1. Also lamp CCGs, SMPSs and electromagnetic ballasts of all kinds.

Comment: Virtually all "cheap" electronic loads have a really crappy PF and high harmonic current content.

Answer (score 1):

Typical Power factors:

**Resistive load    1**

Fluorescent lamp    0.95

Incandescent lamp   1

Induction motor full load   0.85

Induction motor no load 0.35

Resistive oven  1

Synchronous motor   0.9

120V =208V 3ph.

Current = 95000 X1000 / sqrt(3) X V X PF

current= 95000000 / 1.732 X 208V X 1

current = 95000000/360.26

current = 263,698.44 Amps

or 263.7 kA Resistive load worst case scenario

Electric motor PF .85/.35

= 224.15 kA, 92.29 kA respectively......

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a meter that clamps onto the wire and will tell you precisely how much current is being drawn.